# How to Containerize multiple files with Docker

Tags: reactjs, docker, express, kubernetes, google-bigquery

I created a simple application with reactjs/express. The application works as expected after deployment to Google App Engine. I'm attempting to deploy this app to Kubernetes after containerizing with Docker.

my docker file

```
FROM express-gateway:1.16.9
EXPOSE 8080
COPY server.js .
CMD node server.js
```

I have multiple files that need to be containerized by Docker, 'server.js' and 'secrets.json' file. In my docker file above I only have server.js, how do I include other files? Also inside server.js i'm using BigQuery which needs to access the additional 'secrets.json' file, how do I specify the path to this json file? In my code i specify the path as follows, will the Docker container work with the following keyFilename?

```
function query_bigQuery() {          
   const bigqueryClient = new BigQuery({     
      keyFilename: 'secrets.json'
   });
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can copy all required file from the host to docker image and it will able to access other required as same as you are accessing now.

```
EXPOSE 8080
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
CMD node server.js
```

Here `copy . .` will copy entire files and directories structure form the current context to `/app` of the docker image.

So I will suggest keeping only desired files in this context ( mean the directory where you place the dockerfile) to keep the image small.

Comment: awesome thanks, so then i would access the secrets.json with keyFilename: 'app/secrets.json'?

Comment: You can use reltive path, secrets.json and server. Json will on same directory so I think no need to use add `/app`

Comment: yep just deployed it with 'copy . .' and it all works, super happy for this:)